# tkz_euclide: "I do not know the key" errors

Tags: tkz-euclide

Apologies if this is super-basic, but I am a beginner.

I am getting Error: I do not know the key `/tikz/triangle` and Error: I do not know the key `/tikz/input` from a tkz-euclide example. I assume I am missing either a package or some libraries, but how do I find out which ones?

Many thanks

Apologies, here is the code and the error messages:

````tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}  % Allows multiline comments

\begin{document}
% Does anything work?
\comment{
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.25] 
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,12/0/B,6/12*sind(60)/C} 
    \foreach \density in {20,30,...,240}{%
        \tkzDrawPolygon[fill=teal!\density](A,B,C)
        \pgfnodealias{X}{A}
        \tkzDefPointWith[linear,K=.15](A,B) \tkzGetPoint{A}
        \tkzDefPointWith[linear,K=.15](B,C) \tkzGetPoint{B}
        \tkzDefPointWith[linear,K=.15](C,X) \tkzGetPoint{C}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
} % Yes, it does!

% From tkz-euclide.pdf, pg17
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25,thick,help lines/.style={thin,draw=black!50}] 
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(1.25+rand(),0.25+rand()){B}
    \tkzInterCC(A,B)(B,A) \tkzGetPoints{C}{X}
    \tkzFillPolygon[triangle,opacity=.5](A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawSegment[input](A,B)
    \tkzDrawSegments[red](A,C B,C)
    \tkzDrawCircles[help lines](A,B B,A)
    \tkzLabelPoints(A,B)
    \tkzLabelCircle[below=12pt](A,B)(180){$D$}
    \tkzLabelCircle[above=12pt](B,A)(180){$E$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above,red](C){$C$}
    \tkzDrawPoints[fill=gray,opacity=.5](A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}```

And here are the errors:
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/triangle' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ...kzFillPolygon[triangle,opacity=.5](A,B,C)
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/input' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \tkzDrawSegment[input](A,B)
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/input' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. \tkzDrawSegment[input](A,B)
Overfull \hbox (33.29065pt too wide) in paragraph
````

Comment: welcome to the site -- please copy paste your code from start to end so that we can check out the innards

Comment: It is very difficult to answer you without more information. A minimum code would be necessary. A little more would be to know the distribution you use, the version of tkz-euclide. If you have a lot of difficulties you can always send me an email. I am the author of the package and you can find my email on the documentation

Comment: I've edited my post, adding the code - many thanks!

Comment: I'm not finding that code in my copy of the documentation around page 17 (Chapter 1 "Presentation and Overview", Section 5 "Notations and Conventions").  But it's clearly not liking `\tkzFillPolygon[triangle]` and `\tkzDrawSegment[input]`.  What are you trying to accomplish with those lines?

Comment: Many thanks for looking. It's in the section: 2.2.1. Book I, proposition I _Euclid's Elements_ and 2.2.2. Complete code with tkz-euclide.

My copy of the documentation is: January 20, 2022 Documentation V.4.03

Comment: @Teepeemm These are colors that come from the `pgfmanual`  here `4.1.5 The Complete Code example Book I, Proposition I`

Answer (score 1):

You need to define three styles (colors  defined in the pgfmanual ) and in my source. It's my fault, I should have commented on them. The idea was to compare with the codes of a pgfmanual example for a user who primarily wants to do mathematics.

The error indicated in the .log file is :  `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/triangle'`. It is an error that comes from a bad management of `pgfkeys`. Here in `tkz-euclide` pgfkeys is used to manage options and styles. I recommend that you look at how to use the styles in the `pgfmanual` because you can use them in `tkz-euclide`.

`help lines`is not an option for `\tkzDrawCircles`. The options here are the thickness of the line the color the style (dashed or solid) (see how to get the grid below)

```
 \colorlet{input}{red!80!black}  
\colorlet{output}{red!70!black} 
\colorlet{triangle}{orange!40}
```

from Book I, Proposition I 4.1.5 The Complete Code p66

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\newcommand{\comment}[1]{}  % Allows multiline comments

\colorlet{input}{red!80!black} 
\colorlet{output}{red!70!black}
\colorlet{triangle}{orange!40}  

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25,thick] 
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(1.25+rand(),0.25+rand()){B}
    \tkzInterCC(A,B)(B,A) \tkzGetPoints{C}{X}
    \tkzFillPolygon[triangle,opacity=.5](A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawSegment[input](A,B)
    \tkzDrawSegments[red](A,C B,C)
    \tkzDrawCircles(A,B B,A)
    \tkzLabelPoints(A,B)
    \tkzLabelCircle[below=12pt](A,B)(180){$D$}
    \tkzLabelCircle[above=12pt](B,A)(180){$E$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above,red](C){$C$}
    \tkzDrawPoints[fill=gray,opacity=.5](A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The grid : with `tkz-euclide`

```
\tkzInit[xmin=-3,xmax=4,ymin=-3,ymax=3]
\tkzGrid
```

with `TikZ`

```
   \draw[help lines/.style={thin,draw=black!50}] (-3,-3) grid (4,3);
```

The code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\colorlet{input}{red!80!black} 
\colorlet{output}{red!70!black}
\colorlet{triangle}{orange!40}  

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.25,thick] 
  % \tkzInit[xmin=-3,xmax=4,ymin=-3,ymax=3]
  % \tkzGrid
  % or
  \draw[help lines/.style={thin,draw=black!50}] (-3,-3) grid (4,3);
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(1.25+rand(),0.25+rand()){B}
    \tkzInterCC(A,B)(B,A) \tkzGetPoints{C}{X}
    \tkzFillPolygon[triangle,opacity=.5](A,B,C)
    \tkzDrawSegment[input](A,B)
    \tkzDrawSegments[red](A,C B,C)
    \tkzDrawCircles(A,B B,A)
    \tkzLabelPoints(A,B)
    \tkzLabelCircle[below=12pt](A,B)(180){$D$}
    \tkzLabelCircle[above=12pt](B,A)(180){$E$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above,red](C){$C$}
    \tkzDrawPoints[fill=gray,opacity=.5](A,B,C)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I hardly dare say 'thanks' because of the warnings not to, but 'Thanks!'. More important, the code I put up was just taken from January 20, 2022 Documentation V.4.03, ie what is available on [tkz-euclide.pdf](https://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/tkz-euclide.pdf). I'm intending to work through all the examples - would it help or hinder if I bring other anomalies to your attention (by email)? Of course, I'll read up about keys in the pdf manual

Comment: @DavidBrowning  yes e-mail is perfect but if the question is interesting `tex.stackexchange` is better.

Comment: Ok, but now I will also try to post solutions ;)